# JiBX on Android (or any other build-time bytecode manipulating library)

Tags: java, xml, android, bytecode, jibx

I'm considering the use of `JiBX` for a project that will have to run on both Blackberry and RIM. While it seems like `J2ME` use of `JiBX` has been considered by the community (as per JiBX jira tickets), Android is relatively new.

The question is, therefore, this: has anybody had any success (or issues, for that matter) using JiBX on Android, or any other libraries that need to modify your class bytecode at build-time?

There have been discussions out there about how such libs should be runnable on Android (as compared to those using runtime bytecode instrumentation), but I haven't seen too many reports about people actually attempting to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've decided to just write xml parsing code on top of XMLPull api, without any fancy tricks.

If my schemas get any more complicated than they currently are (and I have time) I'd love to experiment with writing an ANTLR-based XML parser generator to generate actual Java code of the parsers for individual schemas.

At the moment, afaik, java generation for mobile is much safer and better than bytecode-generation for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work since android doesn't execute bytecodes. Android's java runtime uses a register based virtual machine (Dvalik) that executes .dex files instead of class files. In theory you could generate those instead of java bytecodes.

Comment: while Dalvik does run special bytecode format, .dex, there is a google-provided tool called dx which converts standard java bytecode into .dex format (look <a href="http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html">here</a>).

Therefore, theoretically, any lib that does post-compile build-time bytecode manipulation, producing standard-compiant java bytecode, would still work for android -- the dx tool just converts whatever the resulting bytecode is to .dex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have used JiBX to build a prototype in android application. Once you've added jibx jars as your android project library, they will be packaged to dex automatically. In fact, JiBX binding works fine with Android. I only need to include 3 jars. Jibx-run.jar, jibx-ws-0.9-bata.jar and my genereated binding jar. The android application can then make soap client calls, xml to object bindings are handled by jibx internally.